# {{ STATIC_URL }} with pyjade in django

Tags: django, pug, pyjade

I have some trouble adding my CSS in my template using {{ STATIC_URL }}. The tag does not work inside the link markup, but works anywhere else. 
This:

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}
```

correctly translated into

```
/static/
```

, but

```
link(href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bla.css"
```

become

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bla.css">
```

I use pyjade with Django. Anybody can help on this?

---

edit
I found the answer:
if you want to use static attributes, use '!=' instead of '='. Example:

```
link(href!="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bla.css"
```

Comment: I keep forgetting to use != for Jade template code I want to escape being rendered. This solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an answer from here : https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade/issues/44

use link href=STATIC_URL + 'css/bla.css'
or link href='#{STATIC_URL}css/bla.css'

In addition to this situation,I met some problems when I use jade to write for loop in the template.I used django template to instead jade's for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the proper static tag

```
{% static "file_to_include" %}
```

and load the static lib in your template.

**BTW:** Since there are no updates to pyjade and its successor recently was deleted from pypi, I took the liberty to revive it: https://github.com/kakulukia/pypugjs

Version 5.0.1 has fixed the incompatibility with recent Django versions.